# How to Edit XML node with same name using XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml

This is my **XML**

```
<MilestoneCollection>
    <Milestone>
        <Description>Departure from Origin</Description>
        <EventCode>DEP</EventCode>
        <Sequence>1</Sequence>
        <ActualDate></ActualDate>
        <ConditionReference>LOC=&lt;FirstLeg.Origin&gt;</ConditionReference>
        <ConditionType>RFP</ConditionType>
        <EstimatedDate>2015-05-10T18:07:00</EstimatedDate>
    </Milestone>
    <Milestone>
        <Description>Departure from Origin</Description>
        <EventCode>DEP</EventCode>
        <Sequence>1</Sequence>
        <ActualDate></ActualDate>
        <ConditionReference>LOC=&lt;FirstLeg.Origin&gt;</ConditionReference>
        <ConditionType>RFP</ConditionType>
        <EstimatedDate>2015-05-10T18:07:00</EstimatedDate>
    </Milestone>
    <Milestone>
        <Description>Arrival at Destination</Description>
        <EventCode>ARV</EventCode>
        <Sequence>2</Sequence>
        <ActualDate></ActualDate>
        <ConditionReference>LOC=&lt;LastLeg.Destination&gt;</ConditionReference>
        <ConditionType>RFP</ConditionType>
        <EstimatedDate>2015-05-11T14:02:00</EstimatedDate>
    </Milestone>
    <Milestone>
        <Description>Arrival at Destination</Description>
        <EventCode>ARV</EventCode>
        <Sequence>2</Sequence>
        <ActualDate></ActualDate>
        <ConditionReference>LOC=&lt;LastLeg.Destination&gt;</ConditionReference>
        <ConditionType>RFP</ConditionType>
        <EstimatedDate></EstimatedDate>
    </Milestone>
</MilestoneCollection>
```

This is my current code. I need to Edit the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd Milestone. I don't know how exactly the syntax for that. How do i edit element Milestone[0] something like this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sample.xml);
var xmldocu = doc.Descendants("MilestoneCollection");
```

Comment: Which field do you want to update?Milestone is a whole element?

Comment: @DarkKnight i want to update the 2nd Milestone for example.

Comment: Which field in the Milestone element? Description? eventcode?

Comment: @DarkKnight EstimatedDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sample.xml);
doc.Descendants("Milestone").First()
   .Descendants("EstimatedDate").First().Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

To update Nth element

```
doc.Descendants("Milestone")
   .ElementAt(2).Descendants("EstimatedDate").First().Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

**Update** This will update the second Milestone

```
doc.Elements("MilestoneCollection")
                .Elements("Milestone")
                .ElementAt(1)
                .Descendants("EstimatedDate")
                .First()
                .Value=DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: this will edit the first Milestone. I need to edit the 2nd Milestone or 3rd.

Comment: i encounter an error at .ElementAt(2). when i remove this i get the first milestone EstimatedDate.

Comment: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."

Comment: I found the answer. thank you dark. I edited your answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmldocu = xml.Descendants("Milestone").ToArray();
for (var i = 0; i < 3 && i < xmldocu.Length; i++)
{
    var ele = xmldocu[i];
    ele.Element("EstimatedDate").SetValue(DateTime.Now);
}
```

> I need to Edit the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd Milestone

loop from 1 to 3?

Comment: You don't actually show how to _edit_  - OP: _"How to Edit XML node with same name using XDocument in C#"_

Comment: i thought u could take it from there ;) but there is the rest

Comment: This only edit a specific Milestone. I need to edit Child nodes of MileStoneCollection